# Error while opening subprocess python

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I get this error while trying to open a txt. file. Please tell how  to fix it .

```
code: subprocess.Popen("/home/yash/Documents/ct.txt")
      time.sleep(1)
error: 
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/yash/Documents/final_downloader22.py", line 5, in <module>
     subprocess.Popen("/home/yash/Documents/ct.txt")
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
     OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text files are normally not executable. What do you mean with "open" here?

1. This could mean "open it so that I can use it in the program".

   This works with `file_object = open('/home/yash/Documents/ct.txt', 'r')` and then using that `file_object`.
2. This as well could mean "let the file type's associated application open the file so that the user can edit it".

   In this case, you would have to find out what the associated application is. How you do this is dependent on the OS you use as well as the window manager/desktop environment. It cannot be answered in a few short sentences.

Comment: thanks for reply ,i'm running linux and i want to open it with gedit to edit it any further help possible .

Comment: @user1779646 Then call `gedit` and tell it to load the txt file: `subprocess.Popen(['gedit', "/home/yash/Documents/ct.txt"])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`webbrowser` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) to open a text file for editing in a portable manner in a script:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("/home/yash/Documents/ct.txt")
```

From a command-line:

```
$ python -mwebbrowser "/home/yash/Documents/ct.txt"
```

See also patches for ["Add shutil.open" Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue3177).